# SQL: Refactoring a GROUP_CONCAT query

Tags: php, sql, mysql

> My eventual goal is to generate tag
>   links for blog posts, the tags
>   relating to the post.

Currently my query has a `GROUP_CONCAT` which grabs relating tags and the returning `tags` column value is something like:

'Brooklyn, Manhattan, New York'

from

```
SELECT 
post.id, 
post.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT( tags.name order by tags.name ) AS tags 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN tags_items
  ON post.id = tags_items.post
LEFT JOIN tags
  ON tags_items.tag = tags.id
```

With this string, in my server-side code I'm splitting it up by the comma and looping through to generate tags. However, now I need to make these links and I need to know the respective id of each of the tags in order to generate a link such as `<a href="?tag=1">New York</a>`. My HTML structure will be as such:

```
<div class=post>
  <h2>Rakim Allah!</h2>
  <div class=tags>
    <a href="/tags/1">Brooklyn</a>
    <a href="/tags/2">Manhattan</a>
    <a href="/tags/3">New York</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

`tags` table:

```
id    name
1     Brooklyn
2     Manhattan
```

`tags_items` table ( no pk ):

```
post  tag
1     1
```

Comment: Why are you using group_concat instead of just returning multiple rows with name and Id as columns?

Comment: @Donnie: I imagine it's because `meder` wanted to get everything related to the blog post in a single query.  I agree - it's a waste to create a comma delimited string when you know you're going to break it out.

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated the query a bit so you can see it

Comment: @meder - I'd just lose the `group_concat` and iterate through the result set looking for changes in the group_by fields to decide when I needed to start a new group.  It's easier than what you're doing, and no slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the ID to each item in the group list w/ a different delimiter:

```
SELECT post.id, post.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(tags.id, ';', tags.name) order by tags.name ) AS tags 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN tags 
          ON post.id = tags.post_id;
```

Now you'd just have to do an additional split on semi-colons to get the id and name.

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing this but wasn't sure of the syntax, I'll try this out.