# sql select query for one row in one table and multiple row from another table

Tags: mysql

I have tables like post,tag and post_tag .. Each post have some tags.. I want to get data like

post 1 with tagA, tagB, tagC
post 2 with tagB, tagD
.
..

post N with tagZ

how is the right sql statement?

post: id(int), title(varchar), text(varchar)
tag: id(int), title(varchar)
post_tag: id(int), post_id(int), tag_id(int)  -> post_id foreign key on post table and tag_id foreign key on tag table.

for example i want fetch all posts with tags title.

1 "post1" "somepost bla bla" "tag1 title " "tag2 title"
.
..

Comment: You want a post _index_ (number), or the post _title_ or another piece of data stored in the database?

Comment: Most likely you need to do some sort of join, would need more detail about your table structure to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836004/sql-refactoring-a-group-concat-query

Comment: @ypercube thanks that's what im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `group_concat` to list all tags for a given post in a single field. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

you can first create a view of tags grouped by post then you can use query to get your desired  result. More specific answer could be given if you actually post the details of your tables and their attributes